# Current location marker going behind other locations iOS7

Tags: ios7, google-maps-markers, iphone-5, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am implementing Maps in iOS 7 application using GoogleMaps SDK. My requirement is to mark all store locations on mapview and display user current location with a man icon.

When resetting current location sometimes current location marker is going behind the store location marker. And other times current location marker is coming up on top of the store location marker.

I tried calling [mapview setNeedsDisplay] before rendering current location marker. But actual issue is not getting fixed.

How can I make this behaviour consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a 100% solution for the query but I have observed that its because the rendering order of Markers is independent or indeterminate when location' lat & long are exactly same.

Hence sometimes Man Icon is drawn and sometimes Store Location is drawn. Hence I did a trick like never match current location to store location.. If matches just I added Man icon marker location with around 10 cm additional to store location value. Then both values are different and Man Icon never goes behind.